# Node logging with Winstonjs logger gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm just started out with Node and I now want to add some logging to my application, for which [Winstonjs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) seems a perfect fit. So I first installed it:

```
npm install winston
```

And then I copied the first example code from the readme (and added the require before it):

```
"use strict";

let winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});

//
// If we're not in production then log to the `console` with the format:
// `${info.level}: ${info.message} JSON.stringify({ ...rest }) `
// 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.simple()
  }));
}
```

But I get an error:

```
/Users/kramer65/mms/testlogging.js:7
    format: winston.format.json(),
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: It looks like an error in the documentation, I can replicate your results independently at this end. There is no `format` property on the object we get from `require('winston')`.

Comment: Check wich version is installed with `npm ls winston` this seems to be v3 code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I tried, but walking around my office chair makes no difference either.. ;-) . On topic: thanks for replicating the issue. I just browsed around the source and found this folder: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/tree/master/lib/winston/transports in which there is no json present. I don't know if that could help us somehow?

Comment: @GabrielBleu - The winston version I've got installed is 2.4.0

Comment: If you want to use v3 install with `npm i winston@next --save` [doc](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Comment: Alright, I just installed v3 and now it works! I guess the readme is already adjusted to the latest version, which appear to be backwards incompatible changes.

Comment: @GabrielBleu - Indeed you're right. Thanks for that! Could you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is compatible with the new v3 wich is not released yet. If you want to install it :

```
npm i winston@next --save
```

Or if you want to stick with v2, you can read the v2 doc on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)

[ref](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1093)